# EF Core 7 : after reading entity including children I need to return only the entity without children

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0, ef-core-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core 7 & EF Core 7 app, I read a chain like this:

```
await _billingRepository.SwlOrdiniInternetHeader
                        .Include(h => h.SwlOrdiniInternetDettaglio)
                        .Include(h => h.SwlOrdiniInternetCharge)
                        .Include(h => h.SwlOrdiniInternetOpzioni)
                        .Where(h => h.SwlOrdiniInternetDettaglio.Any(d => d.Id == swlOrdiniInternetDettaglioId))
                        .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Because I must do some jobs but at the and I need to response the only `SwlOrdiniInternetHeader` to my consumer.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Just create a copy of your `SwlOrdiniInternetHeader` (manually or by using AutoMapper or something similar) and set only the basic properties on it (skipping the child entities) and return that?